# How to declare a Method with two generic type parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Is it possible to do something like having different Generic Parameter type (`U`) for a function return value, while already having another generic parameter type `T` for local parameter?

I have tried:

```
private static U someMethod <T,U>(T type1, Stream s)
```

and

```
private static U someMethod <T><U>(T type1, Stream s)
```

**Edit:**
We agreed to try:

```
private static U someMethod <T,U>(T type1, Stream s)

public static T someMethodParent<T>(Stream stream)
{

   U something = someMethod(type1, stream);  

      ...
}
```

Comment: What error did you get? Your first version looks okay.

Comment: `private static U someMethod <T,U>(T type1, Stream s) { return default(U); }` Compiles fine to me.

Comment: what does 'they don't work' mean, 1st one should compile and 'work'

Comment: I get many errors after doing this change, before that there weren't. I'll try some more things and let you know

Comment: If you only changed the method signature then you would get errors because you'll need to change all the calls to specify what U is.  You probably got away with not specifying T because it is infered from what you pass in to the method, but U has to be explicitly stated.

Comment: "while already having another generic parameter " - if this is an existing method and you've been relying on Type inference then the inference will no longer work - you'll need to specify types at each call site (it has no means to deduce `U`)

Comment: @Feux: The calling code will be in  new edit of my question

Comment: Re: your edit - the compiler can't deduce the type of the result - even **if** it considered the type of the variable declaration on the other side of the assignment (it doesn't), maybe you intended the method to return some class *derived* from it. Add the type parameters at the call site.

Answer (score 9):

`private static U someMethod <T,U>(T type1, Stream s)` is a correct syntax.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

As JavaSa stated in the comments, you need to provide the actual types if they cannot be inferred form the usage, so

```
private static U someMethodParent<T>(T Type1, Stream s)
{
    return someMethod<T, ConcreteTypeConvertibleToU>(type1, s);
}
```

Comment: Ok the problem is, I call `someMethod()` from `someMethodParent()` which signature is only with `<T>` and without `U`, and I mustn't refactor the `someMethodParent()`.

Comment: The type arguments for method `someMethod()<T,U>(T, System.IO.Stream)'` cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Answer (score 5):

This should work.

```
private static U someMethod<T, U>(T type1, Stream s)
{
   return default(U);
}
```

Comment: It works on my pc. What version of .Net and VS are you using?

Comment: .Net 4 and VS 2010, please see my problem on comment one answer above

Comment: @JavaSa - Side note - try not to refer to answers by their order on here - due to the way voting works, the "answer above" could (in theory) change between you writing a comment and the other person *viewing* this question again. You can include links in comments (see the FAQ for how), or just use the other answerer's name.

Answer (score 2):

this works:

```
private static TOutput someMethod<TInput, TOutput>(TInput from);
```

Loook [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk36dx2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after reading all the comments, it looks to me like you have two options...

1. Explicitly specify the return type you need from someMethod in the body of someMethodParent

   ```
   public static T someMethodParent<T>(Stream stream)
   {
       TheTypeYouWant something = someMethod<T, TheTypeYouWant>(type1, stream);
       ...
       return Default(T);
   }
   ```
2. Use object as the return type for someMethod in the body of someMethodParent, but you'll still need to cast to a useable type

   ```
   public static T someMethodParent<T>(Stream stream)
   {
       object something = someMethod<T, object>(type1, stream);
       ...
       TheTypeYouNeed x = (TheTypeYouNeed) something;
       // Use x in your calculations
       ...
       return Default(T);
   }
   ```

Both of which where mentioned in comments to other answers, but without examples.

Comment: Thanks, but it don't work, was trying this according to Feux new answer, got error which `U` or `TheTypeYouWant` as in your answer is unrecognizable.
Not that in this answer we assume MyClass don't have generic parameter in its definition, and that the `U` parameter is only in the `someMethod` as you and Feux wrote

Comment: Now I will try testing the second approach

Comment: Sounds like there could be a problem in the implementation of someMethod. Perhaps not casting the return to U properly.

Comment: Please see my screen shot here: http://snag.gy/VBEP8.jpg
This is almost without implementation :)

Comment: I'm at work, the snag.gy site is blocked here so I can't see the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use U in someMethodParent it has to be specified, just like you did in someMethod e.g.

```
public static T someMethodParent<T, U>(T type1, Stream stream)
```

Now I can use U in the method body as my return type for someMethod...

```
{
    U something = someMethod<T, U>(type1, stream);
    return Default(T);
}
```

Comment: Please see my constraint in Feux's answer that I can't modify the parent method or the class contain it.

Comment: Then you may be screwed, what you are showing in the original question should not even compile e.g. U something = someMethod(type1, stream); should tell you that U is not defined in this context. (See juharr's comment to original question)